# LP3THW - python3 ex18.py (and onwards) doesn't run anymore

Tags: python-3.x

I've just started to take on this book and while there hasn't been any issues that I couldn't find the answer for online, I am stuck on this one:

python3 ex1.py and all the exercises up to ex17.py has run on my Mac terminal. Starting with ex18  onwards it doesn't seem to run anymore. Each time I type python3 ex18.py I get the same prompt to type a command...

I've attached a photo to better illustrate my problem.

I appreciate any feedback. Thank you all for your time.

[visual of the current exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6Vdd.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You over-indented the end of [the file](https://github.com/ubarredo/LearnPythonTheHardWay/blob/master/ex18.py), where it actually calls the functions you've defined:

```
print_two("Zed", "Shaw")
print_two_again("Zed", "Shaw")
print_one("First!")
print_none()
```

By indenting them, they became part of the `print_none` function, and aren't executed (because `print_none` is never called).

Comment: ah.. I see it now. Thank you again for pointing that out for me!

Comment: I'll try to be more careful in the future so I don't ask such questions.  Thank you again though!